# Не могу получить токен

Tags: java, android, retrofit

login.java

```
   public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView email, pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log);
        pass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    }

    public void reg1(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, register.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void vhodakk(View view) {
        if (email.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            email.setError("Введите Email");
        }

        if (pass.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            pass.setError("Ведите пароль");
        } else {

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor);

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/api/")
                    .client(client.build())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();


            JSONPlaceHolderApi api = retrofit.create(JSONPlaceHolderApi.class);
            final LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();

            loginRequest.email = email.getText().toString();
            loginRequest.password = pass.getText().toString();

            Call<LoginResponse> call = api.login(loginRequest);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                    LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();

                    if (loginResponse != null) {
                        Log.d("authLog", loginResponse.data.token);
                       // Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, main.class);
                        //startActivity(intent);

                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("authLog", "Error: " + t.getMessage());

                }

            });

        }

    }
}
```

JSON.java

```
public interface JSONPlaceHolderApi {
   @POST("/user/login")
   Call<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);   
}
```

---

LiginResponse.java

```
    public class LoginResponse {
    
        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("data")
        public Data data;
    
        public class Data {
    
            @Nullable
            @SerializedName("token")
            public String token;
    
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("error")
        public String error;
    
        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("system")
        public System system;
    
        public class System {
    
            @Nullable
            @SerializedName("time")
            public double time;
    
        }
    }
```

---

LoginRequest.java

```
public class LoginRequest {
    public LoginRequest() {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @SerializedName("email")
    String email;

    @SerializedName("password")
    String password;
```

Выдает

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/e.madmeditatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/e.madmeditatio: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/user/login http/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 32
    {"email":"wsr","password":"wsr"}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (32-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/user/login (1208ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 24 Mar 2021 08:53:21 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
    Refresh: 0; url=http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/auth?url=http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/user/login
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    X-Cache: MISS from ics.mf.local
    X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from ics.mf.local:3128
    Via: 1.1 ics.mf.local (squid)
    Connection: keep-alive
    <-- END HTTP (0-byte body)
D/authLog: Error: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Comment: В целом код выглядит рабочим. Почему вы думаете, что он не работает? Может ошибки какие выдаёт? Если да - добавьте их в вопрос

Comment: Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Andrew , в этом думаю и проблема. Я ввожу логин и пароль, но почему-то эти данные не передаются.

Comment: Andrew, loginRequest.email = email.getText().toString();             loginRequest.password = pass.getText().toString(); теперь в логах видно что я ввожу, но токен не получаю

Comment: может у меня запрос не правильный...

Comment: POST /user/login Позволяет получить
данные пользователя и
token авторизации.
Данные отправляются в
POST Body.
Content
-Type: application/
json

Comment: Andrew, я когда открыла увидела и исправила вопрос `@POST("/user/login")
    Call<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);`

Comment: Andrew, но он же сейчас выдал ссылку на форму авторизации Refresh: 0; url=http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/auth?url=http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/user/login

Comment: Начальный URL к API: mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/api дальше добавляете то что вам нужно, в задании в самом начале это описано :)

Comment: Andrew, должно получиться так: http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/auth?url=http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/user/login ?

Comment: Andrew, {"error":"No method user","success":false}

Comment: @vempan опубликовал ответ с тем что у меня получилось, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не туда отправляете запрос, вот есть пример запроса из Postman:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вам нужно сделать такой же запрос только через retrofit. Вот урл:

```
http://mskko2021.mad.hakta.pro/api/user/login
```

данные я брал такие:

```
{"email":"wsr","password":"wsr"}
```

уберите из класса-модели ответа ненужные поля и проверьте урл запроса. По логике если все будет соответствовать постману то должно взлететь нормально. Я бы советовал тестирование запросов проводить в постмане который можно скачать [здесь](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) я так думаю этот ответ:

```
 {"error":"No method user","success":false}
```

вы получили из-за того что перешли по ссылке в браузере) а в браузере апи тестировать без передачи параметров сложновато

Comment: почему-то у меня ничего не меняется

Comment: а что вы сделали? я не вижу что у вас изменилось или что добавилось)

Comment: через postman работает, на вот в самом андройд студия нет

Comment: это все-равно определенности не добавило, вы что-то изменили в коде какой-то ответ приходит?

Comment: все тоже самое , что и в вопросе

Comment: так у вас же там адрес другой, вы адрес урла поменяли???

Comment: это чудо , по сути ничего не поправив, все стало работать

Comment: Ну если вы поменяли адрес, то это довольно существенное изменение :) Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Comment: все тоже самое что и в вопросе, только ответ другой